Find different messages in dataframe by % similarity
Having the following dataframe (sample)
code | msg
1000 | Error in place A
1002 | There was an error in location B
1002 | There was an error in location D, will retry
1002 | There was an error in location C
1003 | Wrong Request

I need to get something like
code | msg
1000 | Error in place A
1002 | There was an error in location B
1002 | There was an error in location D, will retry
1003 | Wrong Request

Filtering "similar errors" but without using regex, as there could be unlimited variations, so I would like to define a % of "difference" to take into consideration as there could be thousands of variations in the dataframe, and the only possible way for narrow it down is by using that % threshold
Is there a way to do it with pandas/python?

Try fuzzywuzzy or rapidfuzz library module.
